# libsvm with precomputed kernel: How do I compute the classification scores?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am working with libsvm in MATLAB and am training and testing a 1-vs-all SVM with a precomputed non-linear kernel. I'm a bit new to SVMs and I am trying to calculate the decision function. I know that for a linear SVM, we can obtain w by (according to libsvm documentation):

```
w = model.sv_coef'*model.SVs;
```

We can then calculate the decision values according to:

```
w'*x
```

and subsequently, predict the label accoding to `sign(w'*x+b)`where b is some threshold.

I am interested specifically in obtaining the classification score from my non-linear kernel. How do I go about this?

Comment: Hi NOP, I just noticed that the OP may focus more on the issue of "precomputed". I added a simple example on how to incorporate the precomputed kernel in libsvm. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to understand what do you mean by classification score. Actually you can compare the probability of each model, and select the largest one, as what I did in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599448/libsvm-evaluating-an-svm-using-leave-one-out).

It is also fine if you are using decision functions. Suppose you are using RBF kernel, and `model.Label(1) = 1`, then you have (if `model.Label(1)  = -1`,  then `w = -w; b = -b;`)

```
[m,n] = size(model.SVs); % m is the number of support vectors,...
                           and n is the number of features
w = model.sv_coef; % m*1 weight vector
b = -model.rho; % scalar
```

Now you are given `v` under test. And you also have `[1,n] = size(v);` Then for each row `i` in support vectors, compute the Euclidean distance (you can vectorize the code below):

```
for i = 1:m
    d(i) = norm(model.SVs(i,:) - v);
    t(i) = exp(-gamma* d(i) .^2); % RBF model, t is 1*m vector
end
```

And the decision function (or score from the decision function) is:

```
s = t * w + b;
```

You can obtain the decision function similarly with other non-linear kernels.

---

**EDIT**

With a self-written precomputed kernel, let's take the RBF kernel as example:

```
% RBF kernel: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)

rbf = @(X,Y) exp(-gamma .* pdist2(X,Y,'euclidean').^2);

% Kernel matrices with sample serial number as first column as required 

K_train =  [(1:numTrain)' , rbf(trainData,trainData)];
K_test =   [(1:numTest)'  , rbf(testData,trainData)];

%# train and test
model             = svmtrain(trainLabel, K_train, '-t 4');
[predLabel, ~, ~] = svmpredict(testLabel, K_test, model);

%# confusion matrix
C = confusionmat(testLabel,predLabel);
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `exp(-gamma * d(i) .^2)` ?

Comment: Is it possible to some how represent by using the vector v under test using RBF kernel as w * v + b == 0 so as to denote a separating hyperplane?